# Issues when putting system outside web root

Tags: security, system, filesystem, forgot-password

Following 'best practice' of putting the EE system directory outside of the web root I have found that I now have a problem with password reset links.

It seems the reset url sent in the emails when a user forgets their password is incorrect. All other aspects seem, so far, to be working OK.

For instance, my system is located at  ../mysystem and specified as such in the config. To access the control panel I would use the URL http://mysite.com/**mysystem.php** which works fine.

However the link sent in password reset emails is, for example, http://mysite.com/**mysystem**/index.php?D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&id=ABC123HASH

Is there somewhere I can configure this reset url?

Answer (score 1):

The {reset_url} will be looking towards the site's index page as set in Admin > General Configuration > name of your site's index page. Is this set?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in my config file I had actually set the cp_url incorrectly.

I am a bad person!

Comment: Proper scolding to ensue. If you could expand on your answer a little bit, to provide more detail of the fix, then select it as the correct answer for your question. That would be great.